# How to generate PDF Programmatically with my company logo using PHP codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I am trying to create a PDF with my company logo using the dompdf library but I have a PDF without my logo. I can try the following code.

Welcome Controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('pdf');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $html = $this->load->view('welcome_message', [], true);
        $this->pdf->createPDF($html, 'mypdf', false);
    }

}
```

Welcome_view:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div id="container">
<h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter!</h1>
<img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>/img/un6.png'">
<div id="body">
<p>The page you are looking at is being generated dynamically by CodeIgniter.</p>
<p>If you would like to edit this page you'll find it located at:</p>
<code>application/views/welcome_message.php</code>
<p>The corresponding controller for this page is found at:</p>
<code>application/controllers/Welcome.php</code>
<p>If you are exploring CodeIgniter for the very first time, you should start by reading the <a href="user_guide/">User Guide</a>.</p>
</div>
<p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds. <?php echo  (ENVIRONMENT === 'development') ?  'CodeIgniter Version <strong>' . CI_VERSION . '</strong>' : '' ?></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and also included dompdf files application/libraries folder:

PDF.php file for dompdf file

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/dompdf/autoload.inc.php');

class Pdf
{
function createPDF($html, $filename='', $download=TRUE, $paper='A4', $orientation='portrait'){
$dompdf = new Dompdf\DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper($paper, $orientation);
$dompdf->render();
if($download)
$dompdf->stream($filename.'.pdf', array('Attachment' => 1));
else
$dompdf->stream($filename.'.pdf', array('Attachment' => 0));
}
}
?>
```

How can I do this

Comment: base_url returns your site base URL, as specified in your config file.  I'd bet if you look at the welcome page in your browser, you'll see double slashes in the image url.
<img src="http://yourwebsite.com//img/un6.png'">
Edit: There's also an extra single quote in the URL:
un6.png ' " >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

`<img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>/img/un6.png'">`

DomPDF needs all external resources to be referenced as file paths, not URLs.
You could, for instance try this:

`<img src="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>/img/un6.png'">`

or also something like:

`<img src="<?php echo FCPATH; ?>/img/un6.png'">`

(FCPATH is Codeigniter's front controller path... the server path to the main `index.php` file that orchestrates everything in CI)

Answer (score -1):

DomPDF requires base64 encoded images in order to display it properly in PDF format.

Convert the image to base64 using this tool https://www.base64-image.de/

It will give a html tag, just use it in your HTML PDF code

Comment: I tried img tag, also contacted DOMPDF support. They only told me to try this and it worked for me